# How does Sipser's 0n1n PDA reject 0101?

Tags: pushdown-automata

In Sipser's Theory of Comp in 2.2 the following PDA is provided for ${\{0^n1^n|n\ge0}\}$.

[image]

I follow how to process `""`, `"01"`, `"0011"`. I want to reject `"0101"`, however it seems one of the nondeterministic paths makes it to accept. I'm probably misunderstanding a detail of PDA -- my logic is as follows:

1. Start in `q1`
2. Take $\varepsilon$ transition, push `$` on stack, state is now `q2`
3. Take `0` loop transition, push `0` on stack, state stays `q2`
4. Take `1` transition, pop the `0`, update state to `q3`
5. Take $\varepsilon$ transition, pop `$` off, enter accept state `q4`
6. The other path is ignored out of `q3`
7. But we've still got another `01` on the input string with no exits out of `q4`, so accept... or assume dead state somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being in state $q_4$ and still having $01$ to read means that the word cannot be accepted (at least with this reading path).

Using this [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#Formal_definition), there is no path leading from the configuration $(q_0, 0101, Z)$ to a configuration $(q, \varepsilon, \gamma)$, so $0101$ is not accepted by the automaton.